# Local extern variable declaration with using-directive in the nearest enclosing scope

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer, using-directives

Is this program well-formed according to the c++ standard?

```
namespace X { int i = 1; }

using namespace X;

int main() {
    extern int i;
    i = 2;
}
```

I get different results with different compilers:

- GCC and Clang gives a linker error: Undefined reference to i.
- Visual c++ accepts the program.

Comment: [Clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mXZcZBUJ0hugmhU5) and [GCC](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HI7rh3yNLZoNmgJf) accept the program. Which versions are you using?

Comment: The latest possible version here: http://melpon.org/wandbox

Comment: I had an error in the example. I have fixed it now. Now both GCC and Clang gives a compilation error (undefined reference to i).

Comment: I meant linker error instead of compiler error in my previous comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[basic.link]/p6:

> If there is a visible declaration of an entity with linkage having the same name and type, **ignoring entities declared outside the innermost enclosing namespace scope**, the block scope declaration declares that same entity and receives the linkage of the previous declaration. If there is more than one such matching entity, the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, if no matching entity is found, the block scope entity receives external linkage.

`X::i` was declared outside the innermost enclosing namespace of the extern declaration (i.e the global namespace) so it is ignored. This means no declaration was found for `i` and therefore `extern int i` is a declaration of a new variable named `i` with external linkage.

Your program will compile, but will not link if the block-scope `i` is odr-used.

Comment: Doesn't [namespace.udir]p2 ( http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udir#2 ) apply here?

Comment: @Supremum That was my concern as well, but I think from this note from  [basic.scope.pdecl]/p11, "Function declarations at block scope and variable declarations with the `extern` specifier at block scope refer to declarations that are members of an enclosing namespace", `X::i` appears as if it was declared in the global namespace but it is not a member, which makes it excluded from the lookup. I'm a little shaky in this area though so maybe someone more knowledgeable will come around with something definitive.

Comment: Hmm... Yes X::i is clearly not a member the global namespace since it is not declared there, but according to [namespace.udir]p2 name-lookup should behave like it was declared there, and therefore was a member of the global namespace. However I think that applying [basic.link]/p6 is not a name-lookup. Therefore I think you are right about that we should get linker error here. Does this mean that visual c++ have a bug for not reporting the linker error?

Comment: @Supremum Yes, I think VC++ has a bug here.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I would have thought that changing ```using namespace X;``` to ```using X::i;``` would compile. It too fails, even though [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388431/function-hiding-and-using-declaration-in-c) seems to indicate that a using declaration amounts to a declaration of in the same region for that entity. I don't understand why it still fails then since they declaration is obviously visible.